# What is the most effective way to get closest target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

What is the most effective and less expensive way to get closest target from these two methods?

Using LINQ

```
GameObject FindClosestTarget(string trgt) 
{
    GameObject[] closestGameObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(trgt)
                      .OrderBy(go => Vector3.Distance(go.transform.position, transform.position)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
         return closestGameObject ;
}
```

or this

```
 GameObject FindClosestTarget(string trgt) 
     {
         GameObject[] gos= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(trgt);

         GameObject closest=null;
         float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
         Vector3 position = transform.position;
         foreach (GameObject go in gos) {
             Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
             float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;

             if (curDistance < distance) {
                 closest = go;
                 distance = curDistance;
             }
         }

         return closest;
     }
```

Comment: No essential difference. The former uses LINQ, which is grammatically better.

Comment: This you can check using Debug.log with Time.DeltaTime, Which is faster

Comment: which one is the fastest? less cpu usage one?

Comment: Edited the post: LINQ, instead of link.

Comment: If you would have tens of thousands objects, and for each you would like to find closest(n closest) objects every frame then implementing quadtree/octree would be good idea. But if you don't have so many objects, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm new to Unity development. What is the best way to compare  these code. How to view FPS in unity?

Comment: OrderBy is a lot slower. (Yes alot slower but you dont feel it because todays processors are real fast!). If you are worry about performance keep the linq version in comment but use second one so you wont forget what is going on.

Answer (score 10):

The first example uses `Vector3.Distance` which requires a quite expensive `Sqrt` operation, while the second uses code that I'd prefer to throw in favor of the simpler LINQ form.

Here's an excerpt from the Unity Scripting API documentation for [`sqrMagnitude`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html):

> The magnitude of a vector v is calculated as `Mathf.Sqrt(Vector3.Dot(v, v))`. However, the `Sqrt` calculation is quite complicated and takes longer to execute than the normal arithmetic operations. Calculating the squared magnitude instead of using the magnitude property is much faster - the calculation is basically the same only without the slow `Sqrt` call. If you are using magnitudes simply to compare distances, then you can just as well compare squared magnitudes against the squares of distances since the comparison will give the same result.

So your scenario is basically exactly why they created the `sqrMagnitude` property... because `Sqrt` is an expensive operation that you don't need if you just want to know the order of distance without needing the *actual* distance for use later.

Personally I prefer this as a third option:

```
GameObject FindClosestTarget(string trgt)
{
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    return GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(trgt)
        .OrderBy(o => (o.transform.position - position).sqrMagnitude)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Best of both worlds... the simplicity (and quite efficient implementation) of LINQ with no superfluous `Sqrt` operations to slow you down.

But as always, when you have a question about real-world performance of your code you should do some careful profiling of each method to see which one actually performs better.  Sometimes the optimizer throws you a curve ball and transforms horrible C# code into quite effective output.

Incidentally, if you wanted to limit your range to a particular maximum distance, square that distance and compare it to the `sqrMaginitude` to avoid the evil `Sqrt`.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:
As Corey suggested this answer does not take into account that the lower Approach is using sqrt, which definitely makes it slower.

I don't think the difference is crucial, but as far as raw speed is concerned, I think the second will be slightly faster, as you are not sorting a whole list (optimal time complexity O(n*log(n))), but only get the one with the closest distance (O(n)).

However, if it isn't a really crucial point in the program, I would always go for the first one... It's just a lot nicer.

Comment: Orderby/sort is trivial in this context. The most expensive one is the computation of distances. so the difference might be very minute.

Comment: @David I'm not familiar with unity, so I guess you're right about that. However, as the distances have to be calculated in both instances, the only thing that matters is the speed of gis setup (which he asked for). Also, when you get lots of targets to compare, the sort() will become more and more recognizable. As I mentioned, I still agree with you using LinQ

Comment: You don't think that avoiding `Sqrt` is going to speed things up a tad?  Performance isn't all about order of complexity :P

Answer (score 1):

If you have too many gameObjects and want to find closest object just for one object, instead of checking all objects and comparing them. you can use triggers. Attach a sphere collider to your player and increase it size until it collide any other gameObject.

Don't think that if you use collider it will always be worse. Try it and I think it will be a better way. (but as I said if you have too many objects to check)